# Accessing Iterable Object directly

Tags: java

I get a iterable list which I iterate using following code

```
for (IssueField issueObj : issue.getFields())
{
    System.out.println(issueObj.getId());
}
```

the list is of following structure

```
[IssueField{id=customfield_13061, name=Dev Team Updates, type=null, value=null},
 IssueField{id=customfield_13060, name=Development, type=null, value={}}, 
 IssueField{id=customfield_11160, name=Rank, type=null, value=1|i0065r:}, 
 IssueField{id=customfield_13100, name=TM Product, type=null, value=IntelliGlance}, 
 IssueField{id=customfield_11560, name=Release Notes, type=null, value=null}, 
 IssueField{id=customfield_13500, name=Request Type, type=null, value=null}, 
 IssueField{id=customfield_13900, name=Category, type=null, value=null}, 
 IssueField{id=environment, name=Environment, type=null, value=null}]
```

there are more then 100 of such objects in the list. is there a way I can directly get the desired objects value without iterating all the values. currently using something like this which I think is not efficient.

```
for (IssueField issueObj : issue.getFields())
{
    if(issueObj.getId().equalIgnoreCase(someId)){
    //Object Found
         }
}
```

Comment: If your requirement is such frequent searches then I think you can go with a Map implementation like HashMap.

Comment: The problem is this list i get from a REST API.

Comment: And the list would be ordered or unordered?

Comment: Unless the API provides some sort of query functionality, this is the most efficient way to do it.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to be able to do frequent searching over a large dataset like you said then you should use a HashMap where the string is the value in your getId(). The big O time complexity for search of a HashMap is O(1) where for a list it is O(n). This would net you the desired efficiency.

Comment: You could add the whole list to a hashmap and then be able to take advantage of the hashmap searching time. So you would suffer the O(n) time to go through the whole list the first time but you would reap the gains of the hashmap assuming you searched this list more than one time.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using java 8, You can try this

```
<your-object> result1 = <your-list>.stream()                        
                .filter(x -> "jack".equals(x.getId()))        
                .findAny()                                      
                .orElse(null);
```

First of all it Convert list to Streams, then you want id like "jack", If 'findAny' then return object otherwise return null

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to iterate the hole Collection to get the desired object, you need to store the objects in the most suitable collection, so if you want to get an element by its id i think the most efficient way is by using a Hashmap , then you use the get function to retrieve the desired element.

HashMap implementation provides constant-time performance for the basic operations (get and put), assuming the hash function disperses the elements properly among the buckets. Iteration over collection views requires time proportional to the "capacity" of the HashMap instance (the number of buckets) plus its size (the number of key-value mappings). Thus, it's very important not to set the initial capacity too high (or the load factor too low) if iteration performance is important.
[Source](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html)

Comment: the iterable list is from REST API cant make changes there

Comment: So make sure at the first place that the API can't give you access to the desired object by its id, most APIs allow you to use parameters on the request url to specify a resource, if it doesn't you need to store the result set of the API call in a hashmap.

Comment: if it's a public API just give us a link to it here